# JAVA regex: how to match with look-around

Tags: java, regex, regex-lookarounds

(EDITED)

I want to know if a specific substring of a String matches a specific regex. Something like:

```
boolean matchSubString(Pattern p, String string, int start, int end) {
   String sub = string.substring(start, end);
   return p.matcher(string).matches();
}
```

This doesn't work when I have look-around, though. Suppose my regex is

```
(?<![A-Z])[A-Z ]+(?![A-Z])
```

I would like

```
matchSubString(p, "XABC",1 , 4)
```

to return "false", but it returns "true", of course, because matches() has no idea about characters behind or ahead.

I understand that there is no way to implement it using standard java.util.regex objects, but is there any other regex library for JAVA that can do it?

Comment: About your example: possible you mean `(?<![A-Z])ABC DEF(?![A-Z])` ? Or I didn't understand you correctly.

Comment: What do you mean by "look around"?

Comment: When you say that it shouldn't match when it's within `XABC DEF` what's the rule for matching ? You want to match 3 letters on either side ? Or something else ? Please clarify.

Comment: look-around means look ahead or look-behind.

Comment: the regex is "look-behind-no-letter" + "one of more letters or space" + "look ahead no letter"

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to do. I suspect that you may want to "check if some part of string matches specific regex, at the same time allowing regex to check surrounding of selected part of string". In that case the answer is: it is impossible with standard implementation of regex provided by Patter/Matcher classes (closes thing you may want is `find(startIndex)` and then check position returned by `start()` to see if it is same as `startIndex` - but this will check only left bound)

Comment: It seems that `matchSubString(p, "XABC",1 , 4)` means that you want to apply `(?<![A-Z])[A-Z ]+(?![A-Z])` regex to a `ABC` string. The thing is, [it matches](https://regex101.com/r/Akkg7a/1). If you use `1ABC2` string and use `(?<=[0-9])[A-Z ]+(?=[0-9])` regex passing `1` and `4` indices, then you will have no match as expected, since `ABC2` is not preceded with a digit *unless* you access that substring before `1` start index.

Comment: @Pshemo  - exactly. I was looking to find if there's a non-standard implementation that supports it.

Answer (score -1):

To match

- two groups of three uppercase characters
- that should be separated by a single space
- and that should not have an uppercase characer immediately before or after

this should work:

```
(?<![A-Z])[A-Z]{3} [A-Z]{3}(?![A-Z])
```

This regex

- matches two groups of three uppercase characters separated by a space: `[A-Z]{3} [A-Z]{3}`
- ensures there's no uppercase character before or after the match (using negative lookahead / lookbehind: `(?<![A-Z])` resp. `(?![A-Z])`

[Regex 101 Sample](https://regex101.com/r/xE5nK3/1)

Comment: I'm not asking about the Regex. I'm asking about the matcher.

Comment: @ModdyFire Then I suggest you add the Java code you've got so far and what exactly the problem is (error message, false positive/negative, ...) to your question.